# half col with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I create something like image below with bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: You can modify bootstrap number of columns to get what you want: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ o create it with percentages.

Comment: Bootstrap does not provide half column layout. You need to override styles in your custom css file to achieve this.

Comment: col-md-3 then set margin in left and right side to 40% i think.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap customizing:** 
Actually Bootstrap  is built on [Less](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less), and also they provide [Sass](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#sass) to manage css dynamically. Less/Sass are CSS pre-processor language (it allow variable,function etc). 
Less files are already included in main [Source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.3.7.zip) inside less folder.

> Follow option 1 or option 2 (I prefer option 2)

**Option -1(local):**
Open `variables.less` inside less folder and find `@grid-columns: 12;` (Line 325).
Change to `@grid-columns: 24;` save and compile boostrap.less file with any less compiler ([koala](http://koala-app.com/)). 
After compile you will get .css file.

**Option -2 (online):**
You can also do it from bootstrap official site Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize

Make sure all checkbox are checked. 
Change `@grid-columns` `12` to `24` under **Grid system** section. 
Then download from the bottom click on "compile and download" button. use in your project this generated css.

**How it works:**

> Now you have to use 24-column-grid `(ex: 100% width=col-md-24)` instead of 12-column-grid.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9"></div> //Same as 4.5 
    <div class="col-md-6"></div> // Same as 3
    <div class="col-md-9"></div> //same as 4.5
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for answer, but I don't want to change other parts of my website.

Comment: Okay. Then you can use custom css and set width with %.

Comment: but I want it to be responsive, for example col-xs-12 in mobile

Comment: I got a better solution:
Follow my answers 2nd option and download source.
Then find out bootstrap.css from the compiled file and copy line no 1621-2832 no.
That mean copy all `col-  ` related css and make a custom-grid.css with copied css.
Use that custom-grid.css where you need. 
For more specific you can use prefix class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LESS/SCSS, you have the bootstrap source and you can use the mixins/functions that are written into bootstrap. To make an col-xs-4.5, you could do...

```
// SCSS
.col-xs-4-5 {
    @include make-xs-column(4.5);
}

// LESS
.col-xs-4-5 {
    .make-xs-column(4.5);
}
```

Or you can recreate it on your own...

```
.col-xs-4-5 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the need for the 4.5 column, you can add it like..

```
.col-md-4-5 {
    width:37.5;
}
```

And use it like:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-4-5">
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/BU4GnihqmP